# Detect Eclipse Buildship

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle-eclipse, buildship

Eclipse buildship doesn't like this configuration line:

```
eclipse {
  pathVariables 'M2_REPO': new File(repositories.MavenLocal.url)
}
```

which causes the gradle-eclipse plugin to produce better `.classpath` files (using the `M2_REPO` variable, rather than absolute path names) - but Eclipse Buildship then fails adding the maven dependencies to the classpath at all. :-(

Is there any way to detect buildship? Some environment variable or property?

I would like to work-around buildship simply by doing:

```
eclipse {
  if (!buildship)
    pathVariables 'M2_REPO': new File(repositories.MavenLocal.url)
}
```

If you know any good way of having buildship import preferences such as code templates and code formatting, I'd also be happy to know.

Comment: c.f. https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/600